# error: multiple repeat for regex in robot

Tags: regex, robotframework

When I try to match a timestamp
for eg

```
2017-05-09 00:14:04+00:00
```

to this regex

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

using Should Match Regexp built in keyword.

I get following error
error: multiple repeat

used http://pythex.org/ to test string match

Comment: Your regex [works fine for me](https://regex101.com/r/v2Y8TM/1).  There must a problem with your app code or something else.

Comment: Use a raw string syntax `r'^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'`